# Jquery Calling a function after appending a <script>

Tags: jquery

I am using a third party  to embed the chatbot dynamically using Jquery

This widget is happened in `var tag`, below.
I have to call a function `PodiumWebChat.open()` which is part of the third-party script. How do I call that function after  `$('#test').append(tag); //testing` statement.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // this code will run when the document has loaded
  // and all elements are in place

  $("#RequestADemo").click(function(){
    // this code will be run when the user clicks on
    // the button we created above

    $('#default').click(); // this calls the click event on #default

        var tag = '<script defer src="https://connect.abc.com/widget.js#API_TOKEN=c0726ce52f4a" id="podium-widget" data-api-token="c0726ce52f4a"><\/script>';
       $('#test').append(tag); //testing

  }); // close the click handler on #RequestADemo

}); // close the document.ready code block.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="RequestADemo" onClick="$('#default').click()" value="Request A Demo" />
<div id="test"></div>
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work

```
$('#test').append(tag); //testing
PodiumWebChat.open();
```

Comment: Is that a **private** api token?

Comment: You will probably need to wait for the `load` event on the script tag to be fired, so that you know `PodiumWebChat` (which I suppose is exposed by the script) is available.

Comment: @0stone0 yes correct

Comment: @Terry do you mean I should call that function after // close the click handler on #RequestADemo?

Comment: You should revoke that token since some people might abuse it.

Comment: No, you need to wait for the load event on the script tag. JS isn't async as such that the script is fully loaded when appended.

Comment: @0stone0 I got it now, it is not a private token, its a fake token :) thanks for the pointer, though

Comment: @Terry thanks, any code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access methods, properties, variables and etc. in the external script you are loading, you will need to wait for the external script to be loaded. Simply appending the `<script>` element does not guarantee that it is fully loaded after.

Instead of composing a HTML string, you can just create a new `<script>` element instead, and set properties using the dot notation or the [`dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) (for the `data-api-token` attribute):

```
const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
scriptElement.defer = '';
scriptElement.id = 'podium-widget';
scriptElement.dataset.apiToken = 'xxx';

scriptElement.addEventListener('load', () => {
    PodiumWebChat.open();
});

scriptElement.src = 'https://connect.abc.com/widget.js#API_TOKEN=xxx';
```

Comment: The <script> has to be loaded with the on click event of a button like in my Jquery example

Comment: @user580950 Then wrap that logic in the click event handler. I'm simply showing the logic how to deal with script loading and calling the method that is only available in the loaded script. _HOW_ you want to trigger the script loading is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Since `<script src='...'><script>` needs some time to retrieve the actual file, you'll need to *wait* for it to load.

After appending the `<script>`, add an eventListener, and call the desired function there.

Small example with a simple script hosted on *filebin dot net*;

<sup>Edit: Added a check to ensure we're only inserting the script once!</sup>

```js
$("button").click(function(){

    // If <script> already exists
    if ($('#insert').length) {

      // Since we've alreay inserted the <script> on previous click, we can just call the function
      doSomething();
    
    } else {
    
      // Insert <script>
      var s = document.createElement("script");
      s.id  = 'insert';
      s.src = 'https://filebin.net/rdj8ag1hhhgx432x/doSomething.js'; 
      document.body.appendChild(s);
      
      // After the onload triggers, lets call the function
      s.addEventListener('load', () => doSomething());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Insert and run &lt;script&gt;</button>
```

---

Demo file can be found [here](https://filebin.net/rdj8ag1hhhgx432x/doSomething.js) and looks like this:

```js
function doSomething() {
    console.log('doSomething()');
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br><span>doSomething()</span>');(1);
}
```